# Redirect when attribute is present?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

To create Honey pots fields I added to my `User` model a virtual attribute that if filled in will send the user back to the root page:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :remember_me, :username, :fake_field
  attr_accessor :fake_field
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable............
  before_create :setup_default_role_for_new_users

  ROLES = %w[admin default banned]

  def self.fake_field(string)
  end

  private

  def setup_default_role_for_new_users
    if self.fake_field.present?
        redirect_to root_url
    end
    if self.role.blank?
      self.role = "default"
    end
  end
end
```

The form works for signing up but when filling in the `fake_field` I get :

```
undefined local variable or method `root_url' for #<User:0x5a06618>
```

Is this ok? Wouldn't this render a 404 for the bot?

Ideally I would want to the bots to land the 404 error page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with MasterBlaster, this is a task for a controller. You also don't need a `fake_field` attribute in your model.

If you want to create a honeypot on your form, just add

`<%= text_field_tag :email_confirmation, :style => "display: none" %>`

to that form.

Then add this in your controller's method where you want to check if a bot is trying to enter:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

    def create
      render :status => 200 and return unless params[:email_confirmation].blank?
      # (your code)
      # ...        
   end

end
```

I also kindly suggest you to rename your honeypot field to something more clever ("email confirmation" for instance) since bots tend to be quite clever on finding "fake" fields.

**EDIT**

You also don't need to inform a bot that his action was unsuccessful, there's no need to be polite. Respond with a nice `200 (OK)`. I've updated my post accordingly.

Comment: I was trying to avoid making a RegistrationsController for devise, this is why I had it in the model or I don't have to do that? Thanks for the tips, I will rename the field as well.

Comment: Your model does not need to have any additional attributes and you have to do this in a controller. Rendering or redirecting from a model is violating MVC architecture principles.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do redirect inside your model. This check should be done in controller.
You can use before_filter in your controller and use method there to check and redirect.

You don't have access to this helper method `root_url` inside model. Anyway, this would be wrong way to do this.