# PHP regex for letters followed by numbers followed by "hotmail.com"

Tags: php, regex

I have a very specific requirement to stop bots attacking my site. They are joining and registering with email addresses of the form:

```
[first_name][numbers]@hotmail.com
```

e.g. `samuel7348@hotmail.com`

Can someone please give me the regex to match this so I can block them at registration?

Comment: You are going to block legitimate users as well.  Have you considered implementing a honeypot?  See link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8873961/how-do-i-add-honey-pot-fields-to-my-forms

Comment: What @MikeBrant said. Go for a honeypot, and/or implement a [simple CAPTCHA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798918/what-is-the-best-method-to-prevent-a-brute-force-attack/15799289#15799289). With your current approach you might as well just block hotmail entirely.

Comment: I use captcha's for my websites. With a little research you can build your own captcha system or you could implement someobody else's system. Regardless, captchas are a great solution that will stop bots, but not stop real users with the "lettersNumbers@hotmail.com"

You might also consider looking into a list of blacklisted ip addresses and adding a script to check those against the ip accessing your page.

Comment: Since thats the standard format for basically all emails on popular freemail services - you're going to catch almost everyone using hotmail with your example/request.

Comment: Why not double opt-in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
^[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+@hotmail\.com$
```

Demo [here](http://regex101.com/r/sV1mF0).

Comment: `some.day.ill.be.saturday.night1995@hotmail.com`

Comment: @salathe but the question was for [first_name][numbers]. It was only for that specific requirement.

Comment: @Kamehameha, indeed... my point exactly. Your regex matches my email address, when it shouldn't.

Comment: Kamehama thanks but it's not working. I've put this in:         `} elseif (preg_match('[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+@hotmail\.com',$user_email)) {
                $json_api->error('Please try again later.');
        }` but it's still allowing them in. any ideas?

Comment: @Seano try it with the anchors.I have just edited it.

Comment: @seano, you need delimiters (`/`) in the regex, like so, `preg_match('/[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+@hotmail\.com/',$user_email)'

Comment: As many here have already suggested, I would highly discourage you from using this regex.  It will block MANY, MANY legitimate users from registering.  It is extremely common to have an email address of `somename followed by numbers@hotmail.com`

Comment: MElliot that worked thanks. As I said this is just a stopgap measure to stop the bots immediately. I'm now going to look into honeypots as a more robust long term solution. thanks all.

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks guys for responding so quickly. I kild teh botz! It's actually an iPhone app and the app is live so I had to make changes in the API. Now looking at honey pots for iOS in our next release. Thanks guys.